# bootstrap button fixed width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/yNsxU/ and modified from button to anchor, which is what I need. I have spent several hours over the past few days trying to find a solution, would be grateful for any help. Have also tried much of the sample code on stackoverflow. I downloaded all the latest bootstrap code as of 31st March 2016.

A good amount of code I have found uses links, as the top code block shows, and it all works perfect. I have tried to over-ride the btn-group but that has not worked.

Some of the code I have been using came from some samples I downloaded, all of it has been working very well. If I can't get the fixed width working I will have change the code to use buttons instead of links.

Thanks very much for the link:

```
<style>
    .custom {
    width: 120px !important;
}
</style>

<br>
<p>This does not work</p>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class = "btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary custom">Save</a>      <!-- anchor fails -->
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success custom">Download</a>  <!-- anchor fails -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<p>This works, but I need the anchors, not the button</p>
<br>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class = "btn-group">
            <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary custom">Save</button>     <!-- button works -->
            <button href="#" class="btn btn-success custom">Download</button> <!-- button works -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: Why do they have to be anchor links? - https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v9ftxdwe/ maybe im doing something weird, but this code seems to work here

Comment: I finally went back to my css file, and found that I had a space between the dot and the class name. A syntax error !  '. my_btn' should have been '.my_btn'. Thanks to everyone for the help. It now works fine with  Bootstrap v3.3.5

Answer (score 1):

You can set `display:inline-block` on your anchors and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from an older version of Bootstrap. The jsFiddle you linked to is using Bootstrap 2.3.2. If you use a newer version of Bootstrap, 3.3.6 for example, your problem will not exist.

If you are working with Bootstrap 2.3.2 and still want to resolve this problem, this CSS seems to work.

```
 .custom {
    width: 78px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 0 !important;
}
```